# Display CSS attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to use JQuery or JavaScript to check the value of a CSS attribute? For example, suppose I have a div with id = mydiv.  I want to check the value of the display attribute.

I try

```
$("#mydiv").display
```

But this does not work

Any tips?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @MoreThanFive did the solution below work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5wyjW/

```
$("#mydiv").css("display");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the .css - `$("#mydiv").css("display")`

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for jQuery's [`css` method](http://api.jquery.com/css):

```
$(...).css('display')
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from css display attribute check via jQuery which is this:

```
$('selector').css('display')
```

the alternative is

```
$('selector').is(':visible')
```

This checks whether an element is actually visible and occupies space in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it : `$("#mydiv").css("display")`